# How to pause all thread groups in certain step until process is finished in other thread group - Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a complex scenario that I want to build in Jmeter test plan.
I have a test plan with some tests that I want  to start  run in the same time.
I created 3 thread groups, the issue is that I want thread group 2 + 3 will hold in  step 2  until thread group 1 (external processes)  is finished.
(the external process is to run jenkins job that uses data that created in steps 1 + 2 in my system.If the jenkins not finished, all the next steps 3 - 100 will fail)
the complexity is that I want all of the threads will start running together, thread groups (= tests) 2 + 3 will be in hold after step 2, and wait that the external process of thread group 1 is finished and than continue the run. Is this scenario can be done in Jmeter? without using delay in thread 2 + 3?
See the attached pic of what I want to create

** steps 1 + 2 in test2 + 3 must run before the external process and step 3 must run after the external process

[[image]][test plan]

[[image]][full test plan - step 3 in test 2+3 must run after external precess]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below plan and i think it should work:-

[image]

Thread Group 1:- Having test action for 5 sec wait before executing external process(Just for simulation). Then Regular expression to fetch a value from the response. In my sample it is "5" in the dummy sampler (External Process) response. Then I have use JSR223 post process to set it as a property.

[image]

Thread Group2 & 3:- Used While Controller to validate the property set in thread group 1 and if not then put a wait for 1 sec. You can use some other sampler like JSSR223 for logging or dummy if you dont want "Test Action" for wait below while controller.

[image]

In this way, thread group will pause at while and continue once get the property value.

**Below attempt for a flag approach:-**

Pre-processor to reset value to something else for while loop controlling.
[image]

Based on the last sample result, set a property using JSR223.
[image]

This is what is used in while loop.
[image]

Comment: hey sunny. I still not understand why the if condition. I do not understand how to use it? I want that all the threads will pause until the first thread is done, so what to use in the IF? another question if I use loop inside the thread group (not all the thread group just one step) is it a problem? once again I will appreciate it if ypu can mentioned step by step reproduce and what to put in the if controller?

Comment: Hello Bastian, For communicating between two threads we can use inter thread communication plugin. We get one variable from 1st thread  (External Process) that makes sure the process is completed and pass it to the second thread. "If" condition is to validate if we got the required state of threadgrp1 and then only start the subsequent sampler/s in other threadgrp. This is what I tried. I will check if there are any other approach to solve it. Loop will keep on do the polling..if it is required then no issue but you can also use wait..

Comment: Is it possible in your scenario to run external process threadgroup1 first and then the other thread groups. If yes, you can use, "setUp Thread Group" and this willl execute only first thread group and other will follow simultaneously. But if you want, to pause other threadgroup in between then kindly ignore this.

Comment: still not understand what to put in the if condition. can you please put PIC of the if controller ? how you configure it? and why there is a repeat? is all this in a loop? I need only one run of the process and one run of each thread group

Comment: Hi Bastian, I have used the same jmx (SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx) file that I have given in the answer and i have used the same "if" condition..nothing changed. It is repeating because I have used 4 loops and 2 thread in each child thread groups. My jmx has "if" "${__fifoPop(cookies,gotCookie)}" != "" which is same as provided in sample jmx..

Comment: still this not work, I want all the threads will pause until the first thread is finished, I do not need any data from the first thread, I do not need anything from the first thread. In the example you told me to download the first thread gives data for the 2 + 3 threads and if it gives data just for the 2 thread, the 3 thread will stuck, I not want this, I want the 2+3 threads just wait untill the first thread finished. not need any data, not need complex scenario of fifo/lifo only that they wait for first thread to finished.

Comment: The problem in your scenario is that you used loop in External process and in thread groups test 1 + 2. can you please try it without loop, that after external process occurred once, the test 1 + 2 running once. (no loop on external process and No loop in the other tests, just one run? (is their a way to create a flag in the first thread group and only after it finished to set it to true and all threads will just wait for the true flag)

Comment: @Bastian Updated for flag approach..Let me know if it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: hey sunny sorry but still No luck, I created 2 thread groups. the first is just flag, and I put in jmeter properties meanning props.put("flag",flag). at the start flag is true, and after 7 seconds I set it to false. In the second  thread group I created a while loop for checking if flag is true, the problem is that is all the time flag is true according to the while loop, even it is set to false. I think i check the flag at the start of the while and not at every iteration

Comment: thanks sunny now it is working just needed to restart jmeter

Comment: @Bastian..If it really helped then kindly accept as an answer and vote if you feel like... Re-setting a property is a catch here. I am also thankful to you for putting this question as I have learned something from it.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling the solution I found with sunny help is using while loop + system properties.
I created in first thread group flag and started it with 0.
flag is system variable so I use props.put("flag",flag) command.
In the second thread group I used while loop with `${__javaScript(props.get("_flag") == 0)}` 
as condition.
I used Test Action sampler, and put it inside the while loop, with action Pause and duration 5000 milliseconds - that the loop will check the flag every 5 seconds.
after the jobs done I put in the system variable flag = 1. and the loop is stooped